# Something is using 64 gigs in "iCloud Drive" and I can't figure out what

Tags: icloud

As you can see below iCloud is using a ton of space

[image]

When I try to manage the iCloud storage in this screen I get this which indicates that its from the top level of my iCloud storage.

[image]

Which seems pretty straight forward. But when I try to look in finder I see this..

[image]

Which verifies the space usage, but further down it says 609 mb on disk? In this folder there is nothing taking up that much space. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to AskDifferent. Could it be that not all iCloud Drive files are synchronized to your Mac? That could explain the disparity between both figures... You can log in to icloud.com to browse and delete your files, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201104 for more information.

Comment: @jaume I thought that too - but the size of the iCloud Drive ended up being a red herring of sorts. I have had this computer since 2012 and it turns out that there was over 60gb of assorted cached files. I used DaisyDisk (the best $10 I have spent this year) and was able to determine that there was a 6 year old cache of after effects files and a random backup of photos? My suspicion is this may have happened when my computer completely died and I took it in for repair at the apple store. They replaced almost the entire computer and migrated all of my data. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

Moral of the story: everyone should download Daisydisk. Best $10 I have spent this year. I was able to determine it was a several year old cache of after effects files and photo backups hidden in the /~Library directory.